# Unexpected behavior using generics with Java Collections

Tags: java, generics, collections

Something weird i've just realized:

Java documentation states that List collection has a method T get(int index) ... as you see the method returns T

However i can do:

```
List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
l1.add(1);
List l2 = l1;
l2.add("Hello my friend");
Object o2 = l1.get(1);
System.out.println(o2);
```

And the result is "Hello my friend" !! ... this does not comply with stated in documentation since the result shall be Integer!

Is there any other possible explanaition?

Comment: See also [*'What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?'*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generics are *compile-time* checks.  All bets are off once you start using raw types...which you are.  This is *why* raw types are dangerous, and should never be used in new code.

Comment: The only reason this even behaves as expected is because every object provides a ``toString`` method, and that is what was called. Anything that was specific to the type would have failed.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughs ... i, more or less, understand what is happening underneath. The Real collection is made of Objects and generics are compile-time checks as Louis states ... but my point is that i have a contract in List<Integer> l1 with Integer get(int index) that is not being fulfilled in my opinion ... i wonder if you see different.

Comment: The implementation of generics only checks that the return is of type Integer if you actually assign it to an Integer variable.

Answer (score 1):

`List l2` is not generic, therefore it's basically a `List<Object>`, and when you use a non-generic list everything added to it becomes an `Object` and it's up to you to use them correctly, or you'll get `ClassCastException`s.

Comment: Yes ... but l1 is List<Integer> and i am using get method of l1 ... acording documentation it shall return Integer object ... and it does not. I can understand the underlying reasons ... but i mean ... is the documentation wrong? ... because it looks like that to me

Answer (score 0):

If you had declared l2 as a generic, then you would have gotten get a compile-time error (if your compiler is configured to complain about these things).

```
final List<Integer> l2 = l1;
```